# Spring - Have TaskExecutor and TaskScheduler backed by the same thread pool

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, java.util.concurrent

I am a bean for TaskScheduler and TaskExecutor as following:

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler s = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

    s.setThreadNamePrefix("Task-Scheduler-");
    s.setPoolSize(10);
    s.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);

    return s;
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor e = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

    e.setThreadNamePrefix("Task-Executor-");
    e.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    e.setCorePoolSize(10);

    return e;
}
```

Is it possible to share the underlying thread pool executor service between the TaskExecutor and the TaskScheduler? Now I have twice a pool of each 10 fixed threads, but I would like to have one single pool of 20 threads.

These pools will be used for @Async, @Scheduled and @Retry annotatons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this by using those two classes, because they are implementations that rely on an internal pool.

However, you can implement your own `TaskExecutor` and `TaskScheduler` class that use a shared ThreadPool.

Note though that a few idle threads is not going to have much of an impact on performance, so unless you know that having two pools is a major performance bottleneck, I wouldn't waste my time.